# Second- and third-order imply first-order with the Euler Method.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the first-order system that satisfies the given initial conditions using the Euler Method for $ y(0.5) $ and $ z(0.5) $, using a mesh size of $ h = 0.1 $:

- $ y'' - 6 z^{2} z'- y'- x^{3} y = 0; \qquad y(0) = 1, ~ y'(0) = 1.5 $.
- $ z''' + 3 y^{2} (z'')^{2} - 5 z' - x^{2} z = 0; \qquad z(0) = 1.25, ~ z'(0) = 1.5, ~ z''(0) = 2 $.

Please help. I just can’t figure this problem out. We’re supposed to use $ u = y $, $ v = y' $, $ w = z $, $ g = z' $, $ k = z'' $ when defining first-order system of ODE’s.

Comment: yes, double checked it. why? whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Let's define the following substitutions:

$$
y' = u \\
y'' = u' \\
z' = v \\
z'' = v' = w \\
z''' = v'' = w'
$$

So we have the following initial conditions:

$$
y(0) = 1.5 \\
y'(0) = u(0) = 1.5 \\
z(0) = 1.25 \\
z'(0) = v(0) = 1.5 \\
z''(0) = v'(0) = w(0) = 2
$$

Substituting, you'll get two first order differential equations (for $u$ and $w$) and three additional ones that come from the substitutions. Those are:

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
u' = f(x,y,z,u,v) \\
w' = g(x,y,z,v,w) \\
y' = u \\
z' = v \\
v' = w \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Then solve each one of them for $U^{(1)}, W^{(1)}, Y^{(1)}, Z^{(1)}$ and $V^{(1)}$.